# how to disable luks partition from showing up in nautlus panel

Tags: nautilus, mount, luks

I have a luks setup with encrypted partition. And I don't want everyone on my computer to see that I have such partition. Unfortunately it shows up in the nautilus "devices" panel as "Encrypted partition".

Is there a way to prevent it from showing there? I plan to setup authentication with a keyfile on usb, but for now I can live without the gnome authentication dialog, and open and mount the partition from command line.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is marked for closure. Regards,